# Automatically add drop down list when inserting new row on table in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a table in Word with the last column with dropdown lists.
Is there a way when I insert a new row I already have that drop down list from the previous ones so I don't have to copy and paste every time?

[image]

Thanks and regards.

Comment: If the drop-down list is a content control you can wrap the row in a Repeating Section Content Control.

Comment: Alternatively, for *formfields*, see:
https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/13955-macro-add-row-table-word-form.html#post38312 
and for *content controls*, see:
https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/27809-code-add-new-row-table.html#post87989, 
https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/13955-macro-add-row-table-word-form.html#post38461, or
https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/43603-multiple-dependent-dropdown-lists-table-add-new.html#post145675

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answers.
I think the easiest and best way is through Repeating Section Content Control:
[image]
[image]

[image]

Thanks & Regards.